# Extend prototype of a type

Tags: typescript, typing

I'm using Vue3 and Typescript. Basically, what I want to achieve is this:

```js
export type PersonId = string;

export interface Person {
    id: PersonId,
    lastSeen: Date
}

export type PersonOrId = Person | PersonId;

PersonOrId.prototype.collapse = function (): PersonId {
    let id: PersonId;
    if (this.hasOwnProperty('id'))
        id = (this as Person).id;
    else
        id = this as PersonId;

    return id;
}
```

and then later in code use the function to keep the code cleaner:

```js
let result: PersonOrId = ...

let id = result.collapse()
```

But as it turns out, you can't `prototype` a `type`. Can I solve this using an `interface`? If so, how?

Comment: `PersonID` is just an alias of `string` and extending `String.prototype` is really bad idea for something like this. Are you sure you don't just want a standalone function `toPersonId(value: PersonOrId): PersonId`? instead? [Example](https://tsplay.dev/rw2n9w)

Comment: @AlexWayne this would also do the job. In the future, I may want to add more functions to `PersonId` and this could get ugly pretty fast with global functions.

Comment: Well you'll never want to to add methods to `PersonId` because it's just a string, and doing that would add it to the prototype of _ALL_ strings. So you'll need to come up with some other approach here. And requiring a small helper function where you need it is a pretty simple thing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try helper functions for now!